# add to std::map with a non-default-constructible mapped value

Tags: c++

I have a `std::map<Key, T>` with a non-default-constructible `T`. `T` operloads operator `+` so that I know how to add objects of `T`. I am frequently in the situation that I need to add a particular value at at a given `Key k`. If `T` were default constructible I would do something like

```cpp
std::map<Key, T> map;
Key k;
T t;

map[k] += t;
```

However I am forced to use expressions like

```
if (map.contains(k)) map.at(k) += t;
else map.emplace(k, t);
```

Is there a way of avoiding the lookup and behave like `[]` would do with a default value? Do I need to change the allocator of `map` so that by default inserts `t`?

Comment: If `T` is not default-constructible, `T t;` cannot compile.

Comment: @Quimby That's why that example is prefixed with "If T were default constructible..."

Comment: Apart from creating a default constructor for `T`, I can't think of any way around that

Comment: *"However I am forced to use expressions like"* - if `T` is not default constructible, then *any* use of `map[k]` would be ill-formed. Did you build this code?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica right, also the ? doesn't compile. Editing to what I am actually using now. However, the `map[k]` usage was only for default constructible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To look-up only once, you might do something like:

```
if (auto [it, inserted] = map.insert(k, t); !inserted) {
    *it += t;
}
```

Comment: As far as i remember this method comes from c++17. Very important to mention.

Comment: @taiwan12 If a question doesn't specify a specific c++ version I would default to at least c++17. It's over 4 years old at this point.

Comment: Structured bindings comes with c++17. As I see loads of people using c++14 and c++11, I just mention that this method comes with c++17.

Comment: @taiwan12: For C++11/C++14, `auto p = map.insert(k, t); if (!p.second) { *p.first += t; }`. and for C++98/C++03, replace `auto` by appropriate type...

Comment: Oh okey, my fault.

Comment: @Jarod What about pre 98 C++ =)

Answer (score 2):

What you want, in general, is `try_emplace`. This is in C++17.

This function will emplace *if and only if* the key is missing, otherwise it is guaranteed to do nothing to the value. This is unlike `insert` or `emplace`, which may freely copy or move your value even if the key exists. This is important if your type is like `unique_ptr`, or to avoid unnecessary copies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(int i) : i(i) {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    
    Foo& operator+=(const Foo& other) {
        i += other.i;
        return *this;
    }
    
    int i;
};

template <typename K, typename V>
V& emplace_or_add(std::map<K, V> & map, const K& key, V&& value) {
    auto [iter, was_emplaced] = map.try_emplace(key, std::forward<V>(value));
    if (!was_emplaced) {
        iter->second += value;
    }
    
    return iter->second;
}

int main() {
    std::map<char, Foo> map;
    
    map.emplace('a', 5);
    
    emplace_or_add(map, 'a', Foo(3));
    emplace_or_add(map, 'b', Foo(2));
    
    std::cout << "a: " << map.at('a').i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << map.at('b').i << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b739a55ad791507

```
a: 8
b: 2
```

Comment: oops, deleted late my comment: I had written that was equivalent to jarod's answer, but then realized it wasn't

Comment: probably want `std::forward<V>(value)` instead of `std::move` since when it happens to be an lvalue, it will cast it to an rvalue and may change value and the caller not expect this.